# problem by displaying images stored in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have images in my blob field in database i use blow colde for displaying image but 
it does not show any pic , someone could tell me  where is my wrong?

this is my model:

```
public function getListUser() {

         $select = $this->select()
                    ->order('lastname DESC');
      $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect ($select);
        return $adapter;
    }
```

this my controller:

```
$userModel = new Admin_Model_User();
$adapter = $userModel->getListUser();
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator ($adapter);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(1);
$page = $this->_request->getParam('page', 1);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

this my view code:

```
<td style="width: 20%;">  <?php
     echo $this->lastname  ?> </td>

<td style="width: 20%;"><?php    header("Content-type: image/gif"); print $this->image;  ?></td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how you can display your image.

Your code should look something like this.

```
<td style="width: 20%;">  <?php
     echo $this->lastname  ?> </td>

<td style="width: 20%;"><img src="/link-to-php-that-shows-image.php?id=123" /></td>
```

Now, in the php file for example (link-to-php-that-shows-image.php). You get the image field from the database and display it. Example..

```
<?php
$image = //get image from database, based on id etc.
header("Content-type: image/gif");
print $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this line of code.

```
<td style="width: 20%;">
   <?php header("Content-type: image/gif"); print $this->image;?>
</td>
```

It's because, `<td style="width: 20%;">` is html element which gets printed before image is outputed and `headers` are send to output image, so you get error

```
Error:: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..
```

But you don't get this error in zend framework because the error display might have been turned off, so have a look at your `application.ini` file for setting.

The best way to do this would be to store image in folders and store the `filename` or `filepath` in database and echo out something like

```
<td style="width: 20%;">
   <img src="<?php echo $imagefullpath; ?>"/>
</td>
```

But if you still want to store image in database then, you can use `ajax` to load image. For further assistance, please comment.

Answer (score -2):

For the beginners there is a very handy rule:

> PHP can't do anything beside plain HTML can.

Now answer yourself a question:

- would you see anything if you paste image file contents directly into HTML code?

And then another one

- How do images being displayed in HTML?

And a final one:

- are you sure you want to store images in the blob field in database?

Comment: As a matter of fact he can. Through the <IMG SRC="data:image/gif;base64,[...]"> construct. But in this case it would be rather awkward. I think.